# How to delete a menuitem in openerp from a customized module

Tags: odoo

How to delete an existing menuitem from inherited module.

Here i have made a new module and i have inherited crm module. I just want to remove Leads from menuitem can anyone help me out?????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `delete` tag in your xml to remove existing menuitem.

```
<delete id="module_name.xml_menuitem_id" model="ir.ui.menu"/>
```

Comment: pls note, you'd better declare the `delete` tag inside a no update `<data noupdate="1">` tag

Answer (score 3):

As Arya mentioned, you can use delete tag to delete a menu. But if you delete a menuitem having child menus, all its child menus will come to top. So its better to move the parent menu to a group. So all the users who belongs to this group can only view these menus

Answer (score 1):

One of these will help to delete menu for Leads.

```
<delete model="ir.ui.menu" id="base.menu_crm_config_lead" /> 
<delete model="ir.ui.menu" id="crm.menu_crm_lead_stage_act" />
<delete model="ir.ui.menu" id="crm.menu_crm_lead_categ" />
```